# why fontawesome loads so many types of fonts?

Tags: font-awesome

I see in the top of font awesome css this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I just wonder why there are eot, woffm, ttf (svg is for IE), fonts loaded here?

Is for browser compatibility? Or just there are different fonts on each file?

Can I leave safely just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this is for browser compatibility.
You shouldn't care about extra HTTP connections because almost all browsers that support @font-face will only download the first file that matches its supported format (*I'm looking at you, oldIE!*).

[Here's an great post by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) that extensively explains how @font-face works.

Comment: I am asking just because I need to edit font awesome for adding new fonts, but I want to change just one of the fonts. Good link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that different browsers/platforms require different font formats, so this is just covering your bases.